# Pandas Error: Chained Indexing error when conditionally changing cell string values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

Hey everyone I am getting an error with [chained indexing/returning a copy instead of a view](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) in Pandas. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
duplicates = pd.read_csv("dupes_test.csv", parse_dates=["Updated At"])
dupe_df = pd.DataFrame(duplicates)
dupe_sorted = dupe_df.sort_values(['Email Address', 'Updated At'], ascending=False)
```

[image: dataframe]

```
cols_to_change = list(dupe_sorted.columns)
opt_out_count = 0 
unchanged_count = 0
error = 0
```

Here is my for loop:

```
for dupe in range (0, dupe_sorted.shape[0]):
    try:
        if dupe_sorted["Email Address"].iloc[dupe] == dupe_sorted["Email Address"].iloc[dupe + 1]:
            for col in cols_to_change:
                if dupe_sorted[col].iloc[dupe + 1] == 'Opt Out':
                    dupe_sorted[col].iloc[dupe] = "Opt Out"
                    opt_out_count +=1
        else:
            unchanged_count +=1
    except:
        error += 1 

print("We're Done")
```

The error message:

```
//anaconda3/envs/DtownPlayground/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:670: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

My output seems to vary, sometimes it works as it should and I get the following output:

```
print(f"Opted Out: {opt_out_count}, Unchanged: {unchanged_count}, Error: {error}")
Opted Out: 22, Unchanged: 8, Error: 1
```

[image: Cleaned dataframe]

Other times it doesn't update any of the values. I guess I'm confused because I'm not using chained indexing and I don't know why Pandas is giving me this warning message. Also, let me know if I should paste the dataframe in a different format for ease of use!

Comment: See the often asked [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SettingWithCopyWarning) on pandas questions.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait for the reply. I am new to coding and I have read the pandas docs, as well as a few of the posts you linked, and I understand the gist. I was under the impression that my syntax was not using chained indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you are attempting to assign a single cell value across a slice of your data frame and hence the warning:

```
dupe_sorted[col].iloc[dupe] = "Opt Out"
```

Usually in Pandas operations, you want to assign entire Series (i.e., column) in one call, known as *vectorized operations*, and not by row and column cell. Similarly, in Numpy operations you want to assign Ndarrays in one call and not assign by cells.

Therefore, consider merging on a [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) version of same data to capture next row values. Then re-assign with conditional logic, [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), by each column. And use the functional form of `==` operator with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) but both methods are valid:

```
cols_to_change = dupe_sorted.columns.tolist()

# MERGE ON SHIFT FORWARD
dupe_sorted = dupe_sorted.join(dupe_sorted.shift(-1), how='left', rsuffix = '_')

# ITERATE ACROSS COLUMNS FOR SERIES ASSIGNMENT
for col in cols_to_change:
    dupe_sorted[col] = np.where((dupe_sorted['Email Address'].eq(dupe_sorted['Email Address_'])) &
                                (dupe_sorted[col+'_'].eq('Opt Out')),
                                'Opt Out',
                                dupe_sorted[col])

# REMOVE SHIFTED COLUMNS    
final_df = dupe_sorted.reindex(cols_to_change, axis='columns')
```

Comment: I ran the above mentioned code and when iterating across the columns I get the following error:                                                                ```TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-adfcd052a0ea> in <module>
      4                                 (dupe_sorted[col+'_'].eq('Opt Out')),
      5                                 'Opt Out',
----> 6                                 dupe_sorted[col])

<__array_function__ internals> in where(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Comment: This might mean one of your columns is not a string column and so cannot accept `'Opt Out'` value. Check field types with `df.dtypes`. Maybe one column is all empty where `NaN` represents float?

Comment: Yes that was the issue, but now I am getting an Attribute error:
      2 for col in cols_to_change:
----> 3     dupe_string[col] = np.where((dupe_string['Email Address'].eq(dupe_string['Email Address_'])) &
      4                                 (dupe_string[col+'_'].eq('Opt Out')),
      5                                 'Opt Out',

AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'eq'

Comment: That error suggests an incorrect reference to a Series (i.e., column in DataFrame) and so does not have the `eq` attribute. It even looks like you may be converting data frame to a numpy array? Check if that specific iteration renders an existing column, `dupe_string(col+'_')`. For this print out columns before looping: `dupe_string.columns`.

Comment: My apologies for the consistent back and forth, I have attempted to debug but am not getting very far. I have updated the post with my code updates, since I am getting a new error. Also, thank you so much for the help I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: You are using two different data frames, *dupe_sorted* and *dupe_string*, which my answer does not do.